# How do I refer to variable from another PHP file?

Tags: php, variables

Let's say: in file Cat.php, I made a variable called $Kitty. On the other hand, I have another file called Dog.php. 
Now I wanna echo the variable $Kitty in the file Dog.php, how do I do that?

This is my code in the Dog.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<?php include 'cat.php';
echo $kitty;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: Are these two separate pages/page loads, or are you simply talking about needing to `include` one file in the other?

Comment: include the first file and `echo $Kitty;`

Comment: You have *files*? Variables don't exist outside *programs*.

Comment: @mike, No just 2 different files, and I know about the include function but that doesn't work, that the problem..

Comment: This is my code in the Dog.php file:

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <body>
    <?php include 'Cat.php';
    echo $;
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>

Answer (score 1):

*You can use the session variable.*
in cat.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['cat']=$Kitty;
?>
```

*Now in dog.php*

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['cat'];
session_destroy();
    ?>
```

Comment: This will work, the other option is to pass the variable via a form (POST) or the url (GET).

Comment: This doesn't work, I don't know why but I just have no output now..

Comment: hey just what have to do is to use the updated code.. It will defintely work

Answer (score 0):

Use `include`, like this:

> ```
> <?php
>
>   include('Cat.php');
>
>   echo $Kitty
>
> ?>
> ```

Comment: That still doesn't work...

Comment: `include` is not what you want to use. Think of it as copying and pasting all the code from cat.php into dog.php where it says `include('cat.php')`